# how does one properly escape the context of a definition when writing one

Tags: terminology, lexicography

When a lexicographer is forming a definition how do they make sure they are not overly influenced by the examples they refer to when forming their definitions.

how do they properly escape the narrative of the example, that might imply association or properties that should not be part of the definition but find their way in?

I have just been calling it 'not properly escape the context' upon which a definition is based upon.

Is there a technical term for this?

Thanks

Comment: They just have to consider enough examples to ensure their definitions get at the real meaning of the lexeme and not its metaphorical extensions. And they then test their definitions on other native speakers.

Comment: @curiousdannii am not sure you mean to but you are kind of implying that your method is infallible, just look at it enough and it will never make this mistake.

Comment: No, not infallible, more iterative. Try working on a definition, see if it fits all the examples you can think of, try it out with more people, and then work on it more. Once everyone you know is satisfied, publish it in a book, and then see what the community thinks. And start working on the second edition.

Comment: @curiousdannii fine but what about the second question? , is there a term for 'not properly escape the context'?

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you mean. But I think it sounds like distinguishing between sense/denotation/connotation or between intension/extension.

Comment: I think you're talking about ontology. What kinds of "things" do we distinguish (physical objects, actions, states, emotions, spirits (including human spirits), living beings, etc.)? Cultures and languages vary, a lot. Consider the characteristics of any [_Entity_ (what nouns prototypically represent)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/frawleyentities.pdf), for instance.